Rate Limiter with SpringCloudGateway and Redis, getting 429 too many requests all the time
I'm trying to limit only the POST methods for an specific endpoint, and "it's working" but don't matter how much time I wait or if is my first request, I get the 429 error message. I tried to configure the limiter on the application.yaml, but it didn't work, the only way that I got some result was using @Bean.
Also I don't know what's the right way to configure redis on the .yaml
I'm using microservices development pattern, so I'm configuring the limiter on the gateway.
pom.xml:
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- RATE LIMITER -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

application.yaml
server:
  port: 8766

spring:
  profiles:
    active: local

  application:
    name: gateway

#  data:
#    redis:
#      host: localhost
#      port: 4242
  cache:
    type: redis
    redis:
      host: localhost
      port: 4242

  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true

          lower-case-service-id: true

      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedHeaders: "*"
            allowedMethods:
              - GET
              - POST
              - PUT
              - PATCH
              - OPTIONS

#      routes:
#        - id: limit
#          uri: http://localhost:8766
#          predicates:
#            - Path=/tech-news/comments/**
#            - Method=POST
#          filters:
#            - name: RequestRateLimiter
#              args:
#                redis-rate-limiter:
#                    replenishRate: 10
#                redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 10
#                redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 20
#                redis-rate-limiter.requestedTokens: 1
#                key-resolver: "#{@userKeyResolver}"

GatewayConfig.java:
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ratelimit.KeyResolver;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ratelimit.RedisRateLimiter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Configuration``your text``
public class GatewayConfig {

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder routeLocatorBuilder) {
        return routeLocatorBuilder.routes()
                .route(p-> p
                        .path("/tech-news/comments/**")
                        .and()
                        .method(HttpMethod.GET)
                        .filters(f -> f.requestRateLimiter().configure(c -> c.setRateLimiter(redisRateLimiter()).setKeyResolver(userKeyResolver())))
                        .uri("http://localhost:8766")
                ).build();
    }

    @Bean
    KeyResolver userKeyResolver() {
        return exchange -> Mono.just(exchange.getRequest().getRemoteAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress());
    }

    @Bean
    RedisRateLimiter redisRateLimiter() {
        return new RedisRateLimiter(10, 20, 1);
    }

}


My goal is to limit the POST only requests to my "tech-news/comments/**" endpoint
But I want a configuration that I can expand to other services/endpoints later
And I want to limit to 1 request per minute but I couldn't find anywere the right way to do it.

Good morning Torres. I managed to solve your problem using FASTAPI.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
